# Do I need OSX to test IOS applications

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests, appium

I'm looking for a new testautomation tool to test our responsive web application for different devices (Windows Phone, Android, Iphone, Ipad etc).  Maybe it is a misunderstanding, but do I need a Mac computer to test a web application through a Ipad or Iphone. For a tool like SilkMobile this is not necessary.

See:
http://appium.io/slate/en/v1.1.0/?ruby#running-appium-on-mac-os-x

I hope you can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

To test ios applications on IPad or Iphone through appium, Mac ios x 10.7 or higher is required.

you may not need real devices like iphone or ipad, you can use simulators, But Mac PC or Book is required. [Or can be virtually installed in VMware workstation]

See the requirements, [Appium requirments](http://appium.io/getting-started.html)

Comment: Thanks Mohan Raj S, for your quick response

Comment: If you can't afford Mac PC or book. You can install Mac OS x in VMware  workstation as mentioned by max.

Answer (score 0):

You can use virtual machine to run OS X and iOS emulator.